# how to increase width according to value count

Tags: php, for-loop

First of all i am really sorry for my english. I try to explain my wanted. I use fpdf to make dynamic invoice in pdf. I have more than one product to add one invoice and i must list them sub-bottom. But products counts change in all invoices. Some invoice has 5 products but some invoice has 2 products. My problem is i use code below but all lines overrided.

```
$invoices_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invoice_bookings WHERE invoice_code = '$invoice_code'");
while ($invoices = mysql_fetch_array($invoices_query)) {

$customers_name = $invoices['customer_name'];

$pdf->Ln(0);
$pdf->Cell(21,123,$invoice_number,0,0,'L',0);   // empty cell with left,top, and right borders
$pdf->Cell(30,123,$customers_name,0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(20,123,$date,0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(20,123,$time,0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,123,$suburb_from,0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(34,123,$suburb_to,0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(10,123,'% ' . $tax_percent,0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(25,123,'$ ' . $invoice_price,0,0,'R',0);

}
```

You can see value of margin. It's 123 as you can see. I must increase this value to 132 for example. And for other product 142 i must make. For example there are 5 products in this invoice i must make like this ;

first 123
second 133
third 143
fourth 153
fifth 163

but i really don't know how can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this. Add a counter, initialize it, and always incrase with 10.

```
$cnt = 123; //Init the counter
while ($invoices = mysql_fetch_array($invoices_query)) {

    $customers_name = $invoices['customer_name'];

    $pdf->Ln(0);
    $pdf->Cell(21, $cnt, $invoice_number, 0, 0, 'L', 0);   // empty cell with left,top, and right borders
    $pdf->Cell(30, $cnt, $customers_name, 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, $cnt, $date, 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, $cnt, $time, 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(30, $cnt, $suburb_from, 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(34, $cnt, $suburb_to, 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(10, $cnt, '% ' . $tax_percent, 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, $cnt, '$ ' . $invoice_price, 0, 0, 'R', 0);
    $cnt = $cnt  + 10; //Incrase it in the loop.
}
```

**NOTE**

- Do not use `mysql` functions, they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.
- Avoid sql injections by escaping your variables comes from outside, or use prepared statements.

Comment: really worked for me and thank you so much. If i ask a question can you answer to me again please. How can i learn last value of this list? For example if the last one is 153 how can i learn this?

Comment: Outside the loop, use the `$cnt` variable.